# Dependency Injection Circular Reference

Tags: angular, circular-dependency

Since I have upgraded the Angular CLI above 1.3 I get Circular Dependency errors.

Here following little scenario.

I have a Parent Component, with the following template:

```
<ng-content select="child"></ng-content>
```

Here is the Parent-Component:

```
import {Component, ContentChildren, OnInit, QueryList, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
import {ChildComponent} from '../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And I need to access the Parent-Component from the Child.

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ParentComponent} from '../parent/parent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) private parent: ParentComponent) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

But unfortunately I cannot get it work.

I always get the following error in the browser: 
ParentComponent is not defined.

Here the detailed error.

```
main.bundle.js:405 Uncaught ReferenceError: ParentComponent is not defined
    at Object.a (main.bundle.js:405)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/features/child/child.component.ts (child.component.ts:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b2ea9a8fb38ffd64376a:54)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/features/parent/parent.component.ts (main.bundle.js:407)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b2ea9a8fb38ffd64376a:54)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b2ea9a8fb38ffd64376a:54)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (environment.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b2ea9a8fb38ffd64376a:54)
    at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:6208)
```

Do you have any solution for this scenario? What really annoys me is that it worked in an older version.

**Edit**
Here my scenario explained: 
Let's assume that the parent is a "ControlValue" component. For example a custom select-box.

The child is a custom implementation of the "option" tag. 
When I click on the option (via hostlistener) I want to update the value of the custom select-box. So I would like to have an reference to the parent. To be able to call:

this.parent.writeValue(this._value);

Comment: *Do you have any solution for this scenario*: which scenario? You didn't tell what you're trying to achieve. Components normally communicate via inputs, outputs, or via a shared service. A child component should typically not reference its parent.

Comment: What is ng-content? Describe your scenario first of all.

Comment: Updated my Post with a scenario. Thanks for the input. But I understand this correct, that it is not possible anymore?

Comment: What your scenario describess is exactly wht Output exists. You emit an event from the child, and the parent is notified.

Comment: So my assumption is the following. I would still need @ContentChildren() as I cannot bind  to events of ng-content. (Which I need, as I want to be able to write  <parent><child></child>...</parent>). I then listen to the children EventEmitter and set the value when the child emits its value. 

But what if I dynamically add a new child. Then how can I apply the event listener to this childs output only. NgOnContentChecked will notify me, when a child gets added, but I cannot determine which one is the new. Or is there a way?